# Bitbake recipe to fetch from Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, yocto, bitbake, repo

I'm facing problems fetch HG/Mercurial repo in Bitbake recipe.

- can't fetch the source URL reported in logs
- tested with env hg clone repo_url works fine
- testet with hg:// and http:// headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right format of SRC_URI is:

```
SRCREV = "tip"
SRCMODULE = "myapp"
SRC_URI = "hg://hg_server_url;rev=${SRCREV};protocol=http;branch=${SRCBRANCH};module=${SRCMODULE}"
```

The key is that **hg_server_url** shouldn't include target repo subname, but include it as ***SRCMODULE*** !
Also you could pull latest commit not with AUTOREV as per git repo but **SRCREV = "tip"**

Edit: Working 100% tip

Due to logic of bitbake classes and nature of Mercurial repo above statement should work but just once. It's that way cause when bitbake checks for cached files it finds "tip" already in cache instead git's HEAD wich is translatet to uniq hash.
To avoid that behaviour we should avoid completly (Mercurial repo) cache when fetch hg repo. This is simple as put in recipe:

```
do_install[nostamp] = "1"
```

That way bitbake always think the recipe is executed for the first time. We not useing cache but always get latest repo commit.